# logical right shift in numba

Tags: bit-shift, unsigned-integer, numba

The following code

```
@jit(uint32(uint32))
def foo(x): 
    return (x >> 6)

print(hex(foo(0xffffffff)))
```

outputs

```
0xffffffff
```

because **`numba`** uses arithmetic right shift despite the fact that the operand is defined as unsigned.

Is there any way to convey it to use the logical shift?

Actually, from the answer by JoshAdel below I have learned a workaround - using an internal 64-bit variable for which the logical and the arithmetic shifts won't differ. Like this:

```
@jit(uint32(uint32), locals = {'t': uint64})
def foo1(x):
    t = x 
    return t << 8

@jit(uint32(uint32), locals = {'t': uint64})
def foo2(x):
    t = x 
    return t >> 8

print(hex(foo1(0xffffffff)))
print(hex(foo2(0xffffffff)))
```

which prints

```
0xffffff00
0xffffff
```

But a decent compiler shall understand that `>>` applied to an **`unsigned`** number shall result in a logical shift.

Comment: If the answer by JoshAdel does not lead you to a solution, you could try `x / (1 << 6)` instead and see if the jitter optimises it to a logical shift right.

Comment: Have tried it. The division remains in the assembly. Too bad.

Comment: Can you coerce `(1 << 6)` to an unsigned type (so that both sides of the division are unsigned) and check the resulting assembly? I'm suggesting that there is a chance that if it sees `uint / uint` it will optimise it, as opposed to `uint / int`.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same answer from the pure python and numba jitted versions using Numba 0.27:

```
import numba as nb

def foo(x): 
    return (x >> 6)

foo_nb = nb.jit()(foo)

print(hex(foo(0xffffffff)))
print(hex(foo_nb(0xffffffff)))
```

results in:

```
0x3ffffff
0x3ffffff
```

The following also produces the same result (to make sure we're not falling back to object mode and actually using the full jit):

```
foo_nb2 = nb.jit('uint(uint)', nopython=True)(foo)
print(hex(foo_nb2(0xffffffff)))

# prints 0x3ffffff
```

What version of Numba are you using?

Comment: `foo_nb.inspect_types()` shows that actually **numba** uses `int64` and arithmetic shifts. This does not solve the problem, but only hides it until left shifts push a number so that the MS bit of a 64-bit number becomes 1.  Then it will give unexpected results.

Comment: Hmm...looking at `foo_nb2.inspect_types()`, it looks to be using `unint64` as the input type, switching to `int64` and then casting back to `uint64` at the end. I would raise an issue on the Numba issue tracker if you think the code gets translated incorrectly. They are usually very responsive.

Comment: Could it be a regression to [Bitwise shift operator bugs #191](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/191)?